# Stripe - STPPaymentCardTextField - How to remove or hide CVC code field?

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

Stripe's iOS SDK's "STPPaymentCardTextField" has 4 fields for generating a token for a card : 1. credit card number 2. expiration month 3. expiration year 4. CVC field

We are saving only credit card number and expiration month/year. We don't need to get CVC number from user. So how to hide or remove CVC field from STPPaymentCardTextField.

Please give me some idea to handle this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**it is possbile** but we need to do this carefully , ok open `STPPaymentCardTextField.m` file and you get the property of CVC field name as `STPFormTextField`

```
@property(nonatomic, readwrite, weak)STPFormTextField *cvcField;
```

finally hide related to `cvcField` where ever it comes on that page around it occupy the **21 Places** in that page , for e.g

```
STPFormTextField *cvcField = [self buildTextField];
cvcField.tag = STPCardFieldTypeCVC;
cvcField.alpha = 0;
self.cvcField = cvcField;
self.cvcPlaceholder = @"CVC";
[self.fieldsView addSubview:cvcField];

- (void)setCvcPlaceholder:(NSString * __nullable)cvcPlaceholder {
_cvcPlaceholder = [cvcPlaceholder copy];
self.cvcField.placeholder = _cvcPlaceholder;
}
```

else make a trick hide

```
[self.fieldsView addSubview:cvcField];
```

Comment: @EricAya - stripe SDK available in objective C - here I answered to override the Code on Stripe SDK

Comment: @EricAya - see this https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/tree/master/Stripe , my answer is we need to override this, not in our class, that the reason I add here bro

Comment: @EricAya - its ok bro

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik - Thanks for your quick reply. Hide wherever it comes. But it crashed due to insert nil object. "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]'
***"

Comment: @Sabs  : I already mentioned we need to go for step by step after that we can get the OP, simple `__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]:`- thi s error means - try to set the CVC field place holder text, so chek step by step you get answer

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik - Ok anbu, i will check this and let you know.

Comment: @Sabs - sure my bro, we override teh code on another work so its take time to find and complete this task, if yiu need the support ask here I will help

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik - Ya sure Thanks.

Comment: @EricAya - Thanks Eric for your quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

**First way: Modifying the framework source**

If you are fine with modifying the framework source, you can do this actually way easier:

In `STPPaymentCardTextField.m` change

```
self.allFields = @[numberField,
                   expirationField,
                   cvcField,
                   postalCodeField];
```

into

```
self.allFields = @[numberField,
                   expirationField,
                   postalCodeField];
```

and in `STPPaymentCardTextFieldViewModel.m` change

```
- (BOOL)isValid {
    return ([self validationStateForField:STPCardFieldTypeNumber] == STPCardValidationStateValid
            && [self validationStateForField:STPCardFieldTypeExpiration] == STPCardValidationStateValid
            && [self validationStateForField:STPCardFieldTypeCVC] == STPCardValidationStateValid
            && (!self.postalCodeRequired
                || [self validationStateForField:STPCardFieldTypePostalCode] == STPCardValidationStateValid));
}
```

into

```
- (BOOL)isValid {
    return ([self validationStateForField:STPCardFieldTypeNumber] == STPCardValidationStateValid
            && [self validationStateForField:STPCardFieldTypeExpiration] == STPCardValidationStateValid
            && (!self.postalCodeRequired
                || [self validationStateForField:STPCardFieldTypePostalCode] == STPCardValidationStateValid));
}
```

**Second way: Subclassing STPPaymentCardTextField**

I don't like editing a framework since I like to update, so I did it this by subclassing `STPPaymentCardTextField` (example in Swift):

```
class STPPaymentCardTextFieldNoCVC: STPPaymentCardTextField {

  func removeCVC() {
    if let fieldsView = subviews.first {
      for view in fieldsView.subviews where view.tag == 2 {
        // set a default cvc for the validator and remove the field
        (view as? UITextField)?.text = "123"
        view.removeFromSuperview()
      }
    }
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    removeCVC()
  }

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    removeCVC()
  }
}
```